# MailKit IMAP Search Body doesn't find email with capital letters

Tags: .net, imap, mailkit

I'm using MailKit as means of email automation. One of the basic search of emails in the inbox is by body text content matching, however if the search is made either with the word capitalized or in uppercase then it returns no entries. This behavior is strange as when doing a subject search, the same word is found when requested in its capitalized/uppercased form.
When looking the IMAP SEARCH command specification it states that the matching is case insensitive, so this is rather strange.

I have a simple email as follows:

> Subject: CAPITAL Word |
> Body: CAPITAL Word body test |
> Body content: Plain

Looking at the logs here's the commands being sent to the IMAP server:

- `UID SEARCH BODY CAPITAL` - this does not return the email
- `UID SEARCH BODY Word` - this does not return the email
- `UID SEARCH BODY word` - this returns the email
- `UID SEARCH BODY capital` - this returns the email
- `UID SEARCH OR BODY CAPITAL BODY capital` - this returns the email
- `UID SEARCH SUBJECT CAPITAL` - this returns the email, showing that the subject search using uppercased words works

The IMAP server I'm accessing is the Outlook server, is this something related to the server, to the IMAP command not accepting a uppercased or capitalized word, or something else entirely?

Comment: IMAP search is case insensitive, so your question is rather like "I have a unit test that fails, the line is assert(foo.contains(bar)) and the value of bar is 42, can you help me?". There are **many** ways to write an email body.

Comment: This seems like a server side bug, but presumably you can work it around it by always using your languages equivalent of word.lower()

Comment: @arnt Not really, my question is really "Why IMAP is not returning the email when I use the exact word that is in it's content?". I do know there's many ways to write an email body, but as the search is case insensitive (which I know as I've stated in the question), it should return me the email in both searchs.

Comment: @Max it seems like that's the case, by using word.lower() I get the expected result, I was wondering if I was missing something in MailKit or in the IMAP search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this situation was being caused by an issue with the server not finding the emails according to my search, as commented by @Max, going to close this question.